# Question on normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H=\{e, (12)(34)\}, K=\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$. Show the following:

a) $H$ is normal in $K$.

b) $K$ is normal in $S_{4}$.

c) $H$ is not normal in $S_{4}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please share your thoughts on the question/any attempts you have made to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

a): What is the index of $H$ in $K$?

b): Think about cycle types. What are the possible images of elements of $K$ under conjugation?

c): This can be verified pretty simply by conjugating by an example element. Note that $(12)(34)$ must be mapped to another pair of disjoint transpositions.

Feel free to comment if you need further assistance!